# Custom ETL Architecture Performance Issues

Tags: etl

I am working on internal tool that loads data from multiple sources and apply transformations and publish Data to network.

I am having performance Issues in transforming and publishing data to sql server.

right now we store intermediate data in lucene. which is having issues on updating.

what are the other alternatives to store intermediate data, which has to be fast and easy to update.

we are doing all this in single thread.I knew we have to multiple threads for better performance but not handling threads in a proper way leads to more problems. so we are using single thread.

Comment: Even a single-threaded mode, you can achieve some good performance, if the process writing to SQL server is working in bulk mode. Could you explain how you currently write to SQL server?